# How to inject a Widget into a custom child Widget and use the child Widgets iteration index?

Tags: user-interface, dart, flutter, frontend, custom-widgets

I am building a flutter app. I have built a class with a constructor in it. I made the constructor so I could customize my ListTile because I am using this class for multiple pages and each time, I need to change the text color and sometimes even add an onTap function.

```
class AppList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
    AppListState createState() => AppListState();

    AppList({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

    final Widget child;

}

class AppListState extends State<AppList> {

  Widget child;

  List<Map<String, String>> _installedApps;

  @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
    }

  getApps() {
    setState(() {
      installedApps = _installedApps;
      getApp();
    });
  }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      if (installedApps == null)
        getApps();

      return ListView.builder( 
        itemCount: installedApps == null ? 0 : installedApps.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return child; //This is where the ListTile will go. 
        },
      );
    }

}

//Just in case you were confused, I used a plugin for some of the features
```

After I built this class, I put it in my Example class.

Example class:

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {

  @override 
    ExampleState createState() => ExampleState();

}

class ExampleState extends State<Example> {

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp (
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold (
          body: Container (
            color: Colors.black,
            child: AppList (
              child: ListTile ( 
                title: Text(installedApps[index]["app_name"]) //this is the text
              ),
            )
          )  
        ),
      );
    }

}
```

Then after, I added a ListTile and a text inside of it. But as I was writing the text I realized that I could not put the text I wanted. It was because 'index' was not defined in the Example class.

Is there a good way to put this text in my Example class?

Full Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter_appavailability/flutter_appavailability.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(Example());
}

Future<void> getApp() async {

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {

    installedApps = await AppAvailability.getInstalledApps();

    print(await AppAvailability.checkAvailability("com.android.chrome"));

    print(await AppAvailability.isAppEnabled("com.android.chrome"));

  }
  else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    installedApps = iOSApps;

    print(await AppAvailability.checkAvailability("calshow://"));

  }

}

List<Map<String, String>> installedApp;
List<Map<String, String>> installedApps;
List<Map<String, String>> iOSApps = [
  {
    "app_name": "Calendar",
    "package_name": "calshow://"
  },
  {
    "app_name": "Facebook",
    "package_name": "fb://"
  },
  {
    "app_name": "Whatsapp",
    "package_name": "whatsapp://"
  }
];

class Example extends StatefulWidget {

  @override 
    ExampleState createState() => ExampleState();

}

class ExampleState extends State<Example> {

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp (
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold (
          body: Container (
            color: Colors.black,
            child: AppList ()
          )  
        ),
      );
    }

}

class AppList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
    AppListState createState() => AppListState();

  AppList({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

}

class AppListState extends State<AppList> {

  Widget child;

  List<Map<String, String>> _installedApps;

  @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
    }

  getApps() {
    setState(() {
      installedApps = _installedApps;
      getApp();
    });
  }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      if (installedApps == null)
        getApps();

      return ListView.builder( 
        itemCount: installedApps == null ? 0 : installedApps.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile (
            title: Text(installedApps[index]["app_name"])
          );
        },
     );
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing a Widget to your custom AppList you could pass a **builder function** that returns a Widget and takes the parameters as required, e.g. the index and whatever configuration is required. Something like the following:

Function definition:

```
typedef Widget MyListTileBuilder(int index);
```

then change the following:

```
final Widget child;
```

to

```
final MyListTileBuilder childBuilder;
```

of course you need to implement your builder method in Example Class:

```
Widget MyListTileBuilderImplementation (int index) {
  return ListTile ( 
                title: Text(installedApps[index]["app_name"]) //this is the text
              ),
}
```

when you build AppList inside example class you pass the method

```
AppList (
              childBuilder: MyListTileBuilderImplementation 
)
```

and finally inside AppList you call the builder, instead of adding child widget:

```
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return childBuilder(index); //This is where the ListTile will go. 
    },
```

Your complete code with those changes looks like this (I had to comment out the references that you didn't provide):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

//import 'package:flutter_appavailability/flutter_appavailability.dart';

typedef Widget MyListTileBuilder(int index);

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(Example());
}

Future<void> getApp() async {

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {

    //installedApps = await AppAvailability.getInstalledApps();

    //print(await AppAvailability.checkAvailability("com.android.chrome"));

    //print(await AppAvailability.isAppEnabled("com.android.chrome"));

  }
  else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    installedApps = iOSApps;

    //print(await AppAvailability.checkAvailability("calshow://"));

  }

}

List<Map<String, String>> installedApp;
List<Map<String, String>> installedApps=[
  {"app_name":"app1"},
  {"app_name":"app2"},
  {"app_name":"app3"},
];
List<Map<String, String>> iOSApps = [
  {
    "app_name": "Calendar",
    "package_name": "calshow://"
  },
  {
    "app_name": "Facebook",
    "package_name": "fb://"
  },
  {
    "app_name": "Whatsapp",
    "package_name": "whatsapp://"
  }
];

class Example extends StatefulWidget {

  @override 
    ExampleState createState() => ExampleState();

}

class ExampleState extends State<Example> {

  Widget MyListTileBuilderImplementation (int index) {
    return ListTile ( 
                  title: Text(installedApps[index]["app_name"] + "  index:" + index.toString()) //this is the text
                );
  }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp (
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold (
          body: Container (
            color: Colors.white,
            child: AppList (childBuilder: this.MyListTileBuilderImplementation)
          )  
        ),
      );
    }

}

class AppList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
    AppListState createState() => AppListState();

  AppList({Key key, this.childBuilder}) : super(key: key);

  final MyListTileBuilder childBuilder;

}

class AppListState extends State<AppList> {

  List<Map<String, String>> _installedApps;

  @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
    }

  getApps() {
    setState(() {
      installedApps = _installedApps;
      getApp();
    });
  }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      if (installedApps == null)
        getApps();

      return ListView.builder( 
        itemCount: installedApps == null ? 0 : installedApps.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return  widget.childBuilder(index);
        },
     );
   }

}
```

Comment: I edited my code but I have an error. I think that I did it wrong. Can you edit my full code? thanks for helping!

Comment: Added your example with changes.

Answer (score 0):

here's your code with the fix:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter_appavailability/flutter_appavailability.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(Example());
}

Future<void> getApp() async {

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {

    installedApps = await AppAvailability.getInstalledApps();

    print(await AppAvailability.checkAvailability("com.android.chrome"));

    print(await AppAvailability.isAppEnabled("com.android.chrome"));

  }
  else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    installedApps = iOSApps;

    print(await AppAvailability.checkAvailability("calshow://"));

  }

}

List<Map<String, String>> installedApp;
List<Map<String, String>> installedApps;
List<Map<String, String>> iOSApps = [
  {
    "app_name": "Calendar",
    "package_name": "calshow://"
  },
  {
    "app_name": "Facebook",
    "package_name": "fb://"
  },
  {
    "app_name": "Whatsapp",
    "package_name": "whatsapp://"
  }
];

class Example extends StatefulWidget {

  @override 
    ExampleState createState() => ExampleState();

}

class ExampleState extends State<Example> {

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp (
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold (
          body: Container (
            child: AppList ()
          )  
        ),
      );
    }

}

class AppList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
    AppListState createState() => AppListState();

  AppList({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

}

class AppListState extends State<AppList> {

  Widget child;

  List<Map<String, String>> _installedApps;

  @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
    }

  getApps() {
    setState(() {
      installedApps = _installedApps;
      getApp();
    });
  }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      if (installedApps == null)
        getApps();

      return ListView.builder( 
        itemCount: installedApps == null ? 0 : installedApps.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile (
            title: Text('${installedApps[index]["app_name"]}')
          );
        },
     );
   }

}
```

you were trying to give title the value of an expression and not just a variable. you needed to enclose it in a parenthesis.

this is considered an expression so it must be written like this:

> title: Text('${installedApps[index]["app_name"]}')